# Modal box vs Quick Time movie

Tags: php

I have a problem where my Modal Box pops up behind my Quick Time Movie when you click on the Magnifying Glass button to search.

http://www.vaal-used-cars.co.za

I came across someone who had the same type of problem but with FLV video and I went and did what the person who replied to him said he must do which was the following.

```
param name="wmode" value="transparent"
```

This is how I've put it into my code...

```
<th width="86%" scope="col"><embed src="images/vaalusedcars.mpg" width="480" height="290" volume="50" param name="wmode" value="transparent" autoplay="false"></embed></th>
```

I've uploaded the page again refreshed but it's still popping up behind the Movie.

Any help on how to get this fixed please ??

Thanx

Jolene

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add the `wmode` attribute:

```
<embed src="images/vaalusedcars.mpg" width="480" height="290" volume="50" wmode="opaque" autoplay="false"/>
```

The parameter you mentioned is used together with the `<object>` tag:

```
<object>
    <param name="wmode" value="transparent">
</object>
```

You might think about using a flash player (like [JWPlayer](http://www.longtailvideo.com/players/)) instead as Flash it is installed on most clients. I only know a few people willing to install Quicktime Player.

Comment: I had a flash player in the first time around but then when I uploaded the page it didn't want to show at all.  It's just a blank space.  I will try what you've said now.  Thanx sooo much for answering my question.  I will let you know what happens.

Comment: Dude I am battling a bit.  You see I am not a programmer so it is a bit complicated for me.  I build this website without knowing DW at all.  A programmer helped me and did the Search Php stuff but when I told him about the video that doesn't want to work he was not willing to help me.  So coding and that sort of thing I don't know anything of and what I know I've learned as I was building my site.  I've tried what you've mentioned on top previously but I don't know maybe I'm not putting it in the right place ?  Can I maybe send you my DW page and you can have a look ?

Comment: I downloaded the JWPlayer.  Tried to put that in I'm sure there is just something small I'm not doing right cause when I uploaded it and refreshed it just shows a blank block but if you right click on that space it says "Save Video As".  Does the video have to be MP4 cause I have a video in FLV format and MPG.

Comment: I just want to say thanx for the JWPlayer option.  I got it to work and the Modal comes up in the front of the video.  Now the only thing is I see there is no Control for the Video.  How do I get the video to have a control that shows the volume loading play pause & stop ?

Comment: @JoleneEngelbrecht: The JWPlayer is only the player (as the name says), you need to pass it a URL of the video you want to play. FLV is one of the supported formats. I strongly recommend you to take a look at the wizard: http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player-setup-wizard/

Comment: I got it to work thanx I converted my the movie to MP4 and it works perfect.  Just want to know how to get a controller for the video now.